# Why does =javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi" load very slow on localhost?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, google-api

When I try to display a chart with the Chartkick gem using groupdate gem, it is very slow for a table with only 3 rows. This is from the console. It takes 22s to load the page!

```
  Tracking Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "trackings".* FROM "trackings" WHERE "trackings"."user_id" = $1 AND "trackings"."tracking_category_id" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["tracking_category_id", 5]]
  Rendered trackings/new.haml within layouts/application (22045.5ms)
```

When I comment out `=javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi"`, then it loads very fast (albeit with an error).

```
=javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi"
=javascript_include_tag "chartkick"
```

HTML

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="/assets/chartkick.self-767a86f502825bd83be8240c9952f03a972f3c42d4c4ccfdb42b6070c5348479.js?body=1"></script>
<h1>Track My Progress</h1>
```

https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#installation

Comment: Maybe it's because `jsapi` is a large library, so not including it in your project just makes it load a lot faster?

Comment: They also show adding chartsync as a second param to the JavaScript include tag. Also maybe give it an endpoint for where it can obtain the data to allow the page to continue loading or place the js in the body at the bottom

Comment: http://www.google.com/jsapi is small. It loads quickly. @CWitty I have `chartkick` on another line to isolate the problem.

Comment: Can you post the whole `new.haml` file?

Comment: @CWitty That would kind of be a red herring, because it's isolated to that line. Even when I comment out `-#= line_chart` and leave the link to Google, it is slow. I can if you insist.

Comment: Sorry can you post the whole new file. Ignore the async comment

Comment: @CWitty Here is the file. http://pastie.org/private/ef0zk85qb8mnmerqtu0iq#1,30

Comment: If you comment out the line to the line_chart view helper does that help? I think the reason it speeds up is that the chart library fails and doesn't attempt to fetch the data from the db.

Comment: @CWitty No it doesn't help. I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112780/why-does-javascript-include-tag-www-google-com-jsapi-load-very-slow-on-loca?noredirect=1#comment55975752_34112780) that it is still slow even when I comment out `line_chart`. It does succeed, and draws the chart. Just slow.

Comment: Sorry man, next step is probably the Chrome timeline

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it go faster by hard coding the protocol, but I still don't know why it was slow. Does it think it's a file path or something?

```
=javascript_include_tag "https://www.google.com/jsapi"
```